# Calculating error in the Input to a convolutional layer

Tags: neural-networks

Say I have a incredibly simple input to a convolutional layer: [In1] <----- 1*1 input matrix

I have two filters applied this input:[F1] and [F2]

They give the results: [F1 * In1] and [F2 * In1]

Then let [F1 * In1] = [Out1] and [F2 * In1] = [Out2]

I then calculate ∂C/∂In1 for each filter: [∂C/∂Out1 * ∂Out1/∂In1] and [∂C/∂Out2 * ∂Out2/∂In1]

This leaves me with two matrices above for ∂C/∂In1 do I sum or average these two matrices to get the final value for ∂C/∂In1

(Also I understand that this is an incredibly simple example in terms of convolution I'm just more concerned with the summing or averaging. Thanks for any help!)

Comment: There's something missing here – you never explain what $C$ is.

Comment: Sorry my bad it refers to the cost !